# Regex for the field validation

Tags: apex, trigger, regular-expressions

I have created a Regex expression for the custom object's custom field Worksite_Street__c and Worksite_Street_2__c that can only contains number, alphabet (small and capital) and #,'-:_@/(). these specials character. But my code is allowing * and + in the field which it should not.

code: // esf is variable of custom object and oldEsf is a Map which contains the trigger.Old value

```
String worksiteStreetRegex = '[0-9a-zA-Z#,\'-:_@/(). ]*';

Pattern workSiteStreetPattern = Pattern.compile(worksiteStreetRegex);
Pattern workSiteStreet2Pattern = Pattern.compile(worksiteStreetRegex);

Matcher workSiteStreetMatcher = workSiteStreetPattern.matcher(esf.Worksite_Street__c);
Matcher workSiteStreet2Matcher = workSiteStreet2Pattern.matcher(esf.Worksite_Street_2__c);

if((esf.Worksite_Street__c.length() > 55 || !workSiteStreetMatcher.matches()) && (esf.Worksite_Street__c != oldEsf.get(esf.Id).Worksite_Street__c)){
    esf.Worksite_Street__c.addError(Label.ESF_Worksite_Street);
}
        
if((esf.Worksite_Street_2__c.length() > 55 || !workSiteStreet2Matcher.matches()) && (esf.Worksite_Street_2__c != oldEsf.get(esf.Id).Worksite_Street_2__c)){
    esf.Worksite_Street_2__c.addError(Label.ESF_Worksite_Street_2);
}
```

Comment: see if this works `String worksiteStreetRegex = '[0-9a-zA-Z#,\'\-:_@/(). ]+#?';`

Comment: @AmanPatil not working

Comment: Updated `String worksiteStreetRegex = '^[0-9a-zA-Z#,\'\\-:_@/(). ]*$';`

Comment: why did you add two '\' because of that I can't save the class

Comment: sorry that was a typo just remove one   `String worksiteStreetRegex = '^[0-9a-zA-Z#,\'\-:_@/(). ]*$';`